# How can I list all ad users that are disabled and still have ad groups?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to provide a report of accounts that are disabled, but still have security groups in their account so I can purge them. Can you help me with this? In my file, it doesnt show groups Name. I only get Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

```
$path = "c:\temp\DisabledUsers_ContainGroups ($(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")).xlsx"
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
Get-ADUser -Filter ({enabled -eq $false -and memberof -like '*'}) -properties Name, Samaccountname, memberof | select Name, Samaccountname, memberof | Export-excel -Path $path -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2
```

Comment: You didn't share why that code isn't working for you. You could use `-Filter "enabled -eq $false -and memberof -like '*'"`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going...

```
Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} |
    select *, @{l='MemberOf'; e={Get-AdPrincipalGroupMemberShip $_}} |
    where {$_.MemberOf.Count -gt 1}
```

Then you can filter out the properties you would like to keep

```
Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} |
    select *, @{l='MemberOf'; e={Get-AdPrincipalGroupMemberShip $_}} |
    where {$_.MemberOf.Count -gt 1} |
    SamAccountName, MemberOf
```

or if you don't like to get all properties of the groups

```
Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} |
    select *, @{
        l='MemberOf'; 
        e={Get-AdPrincipalGroupMemberShip $_ | Select Name}
    } |
    where {$_.MemberOf.Count -gt 1} |
    SamAccountName, MemberOf
```

Comment: How can I get their Groups name. Ive tried this:

GET-ADUSER -Filter {Enabled -eq $false}  –Properties name, samaccountname, MemberOf | where {$_.MemberOf.Count -gt 1} | select name, samaccountname, @{n='Groups';e={(Get-aduser $_ -properties memberof).memberof}}

Comment: MemberOf is all the GroupName object stored in an array per user as above.

Comment: Oops. Found a typo in my code. Must use @ when building custom properties. Fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got what im looking for. Not sure how i can add a new line instead of -join ';' but it works fine. Thanks for your help.

```
$path = "c:\temp\DisabledUsers_GroupMembership ($(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")).xlsx"
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd

GET-ADUSER -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} –Properties name, samaccountname, MemberOf | 
where {$_.MemberOf.Count -gt 1} | 
select name, samaccountname, @{N= "Groups"; E ={(($_.MemberOf).split(",") | 
where-object {$_.contains("CN=")}).replace("CN=","") -join ';'}} | 
Export-excel -Path $path -WorksheetName $date -AutoSize -AutoFilter -TableStyle Medium2
```

Comment: you should really let AD do the filtering for you, your code from question is much better than this or at least the approach you took there

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon But everyone is member of a primary group...

Comment: For a new line you can use `-Join "\`r\`n"`

Comment: I suggest you add `MemberOf -like "*"` to your filter too. Right now you're asking for more results than you need and throwing out some of the results. You can save some time by modifying your filter.

Comment: Also this: `$_.MemberOf.Count -gt 1`. Shouldn't you be looking for a count greater than 0? But you can remove that where clause if you add `MemberOf` to the filter.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I tried where-object {$_.contains("CN=")}).replace("CN=","") -join "`r`n"}} but the output displays the result in the same line which is hard to read